# Where does Empathy go when minimized in Gnome3 shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, empathy

I'm trying out Gnome-shell instead of Unity and loving it.  Unfortunately I can't figure out where Empathy goes when I click the close button (there is no minimize button.)  I'm still logged in because I still get chat messages from people, but I can find no way to open the list of contacts to chat with.

There's no icon in the bottom right pop-up tray for it unless I have a pending message, and I can't use that icon to get the user list.  The only way I've found to get the user list is to launch Empathy from dash again.

My user name in the top right of the screen lists me as available for chat, but also has no way to open the list of people I can message.

I'm wondering if something went wrong in my Gnome 3 setup somehow that has caused this because I can't find any other people complaining of this specific issue.

Comment: And just to clarify - no, when I "minimize" Emapthy it's not still visible in Dash.

Comment: Nothing went wrong in your Gnome 3 setup. This is how Empathy behaves.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the close button, you've closed the window. So it's gone.  Empathy is still running, but without any open windows. There's info on restoring minimize/maximize buttons here:

[How can I move Chrome's buttons to the right in Gnome3's Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78288/how-can-i-move-chromes-buttons-to-the-right-in-gnome3s-shell)

Comment: I'm not following how a chrome fix is supposed to fix this, especially since Chrome and all my other windows already have minimize buttons on them (on the right.)

Answer (score 0):

It sort of hides, but you can unhide it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> whenever you want. Also mind that when somebody talks to you, you will be able to reply through a small window in the bottom.

Comment: Actually, alt+tab does not show Empathy in the list.  It's just not accessible without launching it (again) from the Dash menu.

Answer (score 0):

Open Activites and right click on the empathy icon (in the dock or in the main Applications list) and select "New Window."

I have to say it isn't the clean, but it should work.