# How can I move Chrome's buttons to the right in Gnome3's Shell

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, window-buttons

I switched from Unity to Gnome Shell in Ubuntu. Now Chrome has the buttons on the left side, but I want them on the right. How can I fix this without switching to the system titlebar?

I also tried gconf-editor and modifying apps>metacity>general>button_layout, but that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That works for me in Gnome Shell and Chrome 15.0.874.120. Try from the command line:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

Answer (score 24):

Won't let me add a comment to the chosen answer

if you use

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

You'll keep all the buttons

Answer (score 3):

You alternatively make chrome use the system theme in options under appearance. This is for people who are still searching for how to make chrome take on a more native appearance.

Answer (score -1):

Works only for all metacity windows, but not for the integrated in new Chrome buttons...
To make it work, just need to check the option to see title bar in the browser's settings..

Comment: It works for me with the integrated buttons.